# NEO4J | Causal Cluster - How to change user password (across all instances)

Tags: neo4j

**Problem**: Change the user password of account `neo4j`

**Attempted Flow**:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST \ 
  -d '{"password": "newPwd"}' \
  -u neo4j:"oldPwd" \ 
  http://IP-ADDR:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

**Observation**:

1. Only one instance has reflecting with the changed user password.

**Expected**:

1. **All instances** of the Causal Cluster should be applied with the password changes.

---

- Version: Neo4j 3.5.1
- Database type: Causal Cluster (3 instances)

---

**Update**: NEO4J Team Replied in their chat

> Neo4j 4.x no longer has this limitation and users/roles are auto
> propagated amongst members
>
> Ref:
> https://community.neo4j.com/t/causal-cluster-how-to-change-user-password-across-all-instances/31449

Comment: Neo4j Team Reply: https://community.neo4j.com/t/causal-cluster-how-to-change-user-password-across-all-instances/31449

"Neo4j 4.x no longer has this limitation and users/roles are auto propagated amongst members"

Answer (score 1):

In 3.5 after changing the password in one member, you need to copy the neo4j_directory/data/dbms/auth file manually to all other cluster members , there is no need to shutdown the members, the file will be re-read autimatically in few minutes after you copy. ( The issue is fixed in neo4j 4.X )